Postgresql tuning
We have migrated our PROD DB to new server with 24GB RAM.
Based on that value it is possible to tune some PG configuration values?
I think we can increase some values.
Is it possible to suggest which value can be increased like shared_buffers to 50% of RAM, etc?

Without knowing basics like OLAP/OLTP and many other important factors, advice is impossible to purvey!

https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ if you want a formula. Consider though that proper parameter tuning can only be done by continuously observing the system metrics and determining the bottleneck(s).
